# How should I implement a thread pool in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to port a C# thread pool into C++ but have encountered some serious problems. Some of the features of the C# thread pool are:

1. Define the maximum number of concurrent threads explicitly
2. Each thread is defined using a AutoResetEvent
3. Each workitem in the thread are overloaded so that it can have delegate functions as its private members.

For example,

```
private static void RunOrBlock(WorkItem workitem) {
  workItem.ThreadIndex = WaitHandle.WaitAny(threadUnoccupied);
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(threadWorker, workItem);
}

private static void threadWorker(object o) {
  WorkItem workItem = (workItem) o;
  workItem.Run();
  threadUnoccupied[workItem.ThreadIndex].Set();
}
```

WorkItem is defined as:

```
public abstract class WorkItem {
  protected int threadIndex;
  public abstract void Run();
  public int ThreadIndex {
    get { return threadIndex; }
    set { threadIndex = value; } 
  }
```

Does someone know if there exists a open-source threading pool that has similar functionalities? If not, what will be the correct way to implement such a threading pool? Thanks!

Comment: Try Boost.Threadpool :-)

Comment: Two things: 1) it takes probably a week to write a reasonably good thread pool implementation, especially if using C++11; 2) there is no Boost.Threadpool library, and I can't recommend threadpool on sourceforge, it's quite inefficient and naive design.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: There is this simple library that can give some ideas -> https://code.google.com/p/threadpool11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain about their specific functionalities, but for open source threadpools in c++ look at [boost threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) or [zthreads](http://zthread.sourceforge.net).

If you just need a threadpool like functionality and have a compiler which supports it, you could also just use `openmp 3.0` `tasks`. This is what I would choose if possible, since `"boost" threadpool` didn't look very convincing at a glance (so might have quite a bit of overhead) and it seems like `zthreads` isn't actively developed anymore (at least at first glance, I'm not 100% sure).

In the not exactly foss, but might be usable if you can live with the licensing (or are ready to invest quite a bit of money...) `Intel Threading Building Blocks` is pretty much treadpool based